# Benchmarking solutions to find a value in an array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection, benchmarking, v8

I was curious and I wanted to benchmark which function was the fastest when you want to find a value in an array of possibilities.

I've done this research by writing some code inside the Google Chrome console.

Here is the functions I wanted to compare: (X || Y || Z ...), array.includes, array.indexOf, regex.test, array.find. I'm just gonna use the first 2 functions in my example.

Here is my setup :

```
var array = [181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 190];

function orLogicSolution(q) {
    return q === 181 || q === 182 || q === 183 || q === 184 || q === 185 || q === 190;
}

function includesSolution(q) {
    return array.includes(q);
}

function BENCHMARK() {
    this.number = 6000000;

    var items = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < this.number; j++) {
        items.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 1000, 10));
    }

    this.items = items;
}

BENCHMARK.prototype.solve = function (testedFunction) {
    var repetition = 10;
    var result = 0;
    var i, k, then, now;

    for (k = 0; k < repetition; k++) {
        then = Date.now();

        for (i = 0; i < this.number; i++) {
            testedFunction(this.items[i]);
        }

        now = Date.now();

        result += now - then;
    }

    return Math.round(result / repetition);
};
```

Now that I got my setup, I tried to launch my test by writing this:

```
console.log('includesSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(includesSolution) + 'ms');
console.log('orLogicSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(orLogicSolution) + 'ms');
```

My results were:

> includesSolution 4ms
>
> orLogicSolution 41ms

Then, I refreshed my browser, copy / pasted my setup again, but this time I launched my test by doing the opposite:

```
console.log('orLogicSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(orLogicSolution) + 'ms');
console.log('includesSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(includesSolution) + 'ms');
```

My results were:

> orLogicSolution 4ms
>
> includesSolution 78ms

Which completely contradicts the first test.

After that, I tried on a fresh browser and setup again:

```
console.log('orLogicSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(orLogicSolution) + 'ms');
console.log('includesSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(includesSolution) + 'ms');
console.log('orLogicSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(orLogicSolution) + 'ms');
console.log('includesSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(includesSolution) + 'ms');
```

My results were:

> orLogicSolution 4ms
>
> includesSolution 78ms
>
> orLogicSolution 38ms
>
> includesSolution 81ms

I've tried on Safari, it seems to work perfectly fine:

> [Log] orLogicSolution 77ms
>
> [Log] includesSolution 144ms
>
> [Log] orLogicSolution 75ms
>
> [Log] includesSolution 145ms

My guess is that it has something to do with Chrome and his management of garbage collection, or function memory management.

So here is my question: why is this behavior happening, and is there a way to modify this code to get the correct results ?

EDIT:
The only way to get the correct answer is to rewrite completely the solve function, but we lose the point of scalability.

```
console.log('includesSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(includesSolution) + 'ms');
BENCHMARK.prototype.solve = function (testedFunction) {
    var repetition = 10;
    var result = 0;
    var i, k, then, now;

    for (k = 0; k < repetition; k++) {
        then = Date.now();

        for (i = 0; i < this.number; i++) {
            testedFunction(this.items[i]);
        }

        now = Date.now();

        result += now - then;
    }

    return Math.round(result / repetition);
};
console.log('orLogicSolution ' + new BENCHMARK().solve(orLogicSolution) + 'ms');
```

And we got those results :

> includesSolution 3ms
>
> orLogicSolution 4ms

So yeah, I don't understand why D: